# Quantization of Bert Classifier Model

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, bert-language-model, tensorflow-model-garden

I am currently trying to quantize a bert-classifier model but am running into an error, I was wondering if this is even supported at the moment or not? For clarity I am asking if quantization is supported on the BERT Classifier super class in the tensorflow-model-garden? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Quantizing the standard BERT classifier is probably not a good way to go, if you are interesting in running a BERT-like model on a resource constrained edge device (like a mobile phone). For your specific question, I believe the answer is 'no, quantization of the standard BERT is not supported.' However, a better answer is probably to use one of the smaller BERT-type models that have been created for the edge use case, such as MobileBERT:

https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/mobilebert

The above link includes scripts for fine-tuning and then converting to TF Lite format in order to run on device.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! That answers my question sufficiently. Do you know of a reason why the standard BERT model is not able to be quantized but smaller version of the BERT model are? Just asking out of personal interest. Thanks!